# A Derangements Problem in Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Exercise.** Let $n\geq1$ be a natural number. Denote $[n]=\{1,2,...,n\}$. Let $S_n$ be the set of permutations $\pi:[n]\rightarrow[n]$. Determine the norm of the set $$\{(S_n,i,j)\in S_n\times[n]\times[n]:\pi(i)=i,\pi(j)=j\}.$$

Do not express your answer by $\sum$ or $(...)$.

**Attempt.** **Case 1.** Suppose that $i=j$. Then, we choose one element for the existence of a fixed point: There are $n\choose1$ ways to do so. Now, we have to derange the remaining elements – we can do this in $(n-1)!\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ ways.

Thus, in this case, we have $${n\choose1}(n-1)!\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=n!\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$
permutations.

**Case 2.** $i\ne j$. In this case, we have to choose two fixed points – We have $n\choose2$ ways to choose them. We have to derange the remaining $(n-2)$ elements. This can be done in: $(n-2)!\sum^{n-2}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ ways. Hence the total number of permutations in this case is:$${n\choose2}(n-2)!\sum^{n-2}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=\frac{n!}2\sum^{n-2}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.$$

However, When I try to sum up the result of the two cases above, I obtain:$$n!\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}+\frac{n!}2\sum^{n-2}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=\frac12\left(3n!\sum^{n-2}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}+(-1)^{n-1}\frac n2\right).$$

Unfortunately, this answer is expressed as a sum, in contrast to what was required.

Is there a way to express the answer explicitly, or maybe my entire deduction process is incorrect? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why do you assume that you need a derangement for the rest of options?

Comment: You don't need to derange the remaining elements. There's nothing in the definition of the set that says $\pi(k)\neq k$ for $k\neq i,j$.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe The set is about the existence of at most two fixed points, isn't it? If I do not derange the rest of the elements, will I not obtain more than two fixed points?

Comment: The set that you describe has no conditions on the permutations other than $\pi(i)=i$ and $\pi(j)=j$. Maybe you could try listing the set explicitly for $n=3$.

Comment: No, the set is **not** about the existence of at most two fixed points, **unless** you have mis-stated the original wording of the problem.  If (for example) the pertinent elements $(i)$ and $(j)$ are distinct, then the set is about the existence of **at least** two fixed points.

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: Thank you! Now the exercise is much easier!

Comment: Further, you can use **meta-cheating** to show that the Math expressed near the end of your answer can't be what the problem composer intended, because : [1] you are specifically prohibited from using the $~\displaystyle \sum ~$ symbol in your answer and [2] there does not seem to be an alternate way of expressing the corresponding math without the $~\displaystyle \sum ~$ symbol.